# Get multiple values from onChange row event

Tags: google-apps-script, multiple-columns, onchange

Am stuck. Have looked high and low for a method to pull multiple edited values from a google spreadsheet row. Have trawled through the google App Script list of commands. Nothing found.

A form is submitted to a google sheet that can change multiple columns per row per event.

Basically, I have an onChange(e) script that reads the changed row. It is installed and working. I can pull from the changed row single values, row and column details etc. However, despite using a variety of combinations I cannot pull a multiple row changes from a form that updates the row with multiple column changes per row. I have tried array variables all to no avail. It still only pulls a single column change per row. Have also tried A1Notation again to no avail.

Is there any way to pull changes in columns 3, 9, 17 for example?

I am happy to work through the problem if someone can just let me know a single line function command or a way that it is done. Is there something like columnChanges = [ e.source.getXXXXXX().getYYYYYY() ];  that will allow me to pull array variables that have the changed values?

Any help appreciated but I am now desperately stuck with this and prefer to avoid keeping duplicate spreadsheet and then cross checking what has changed between the two.

Comment: Does it help you to realize that the only changes it on change will respond to our user changes not script changes

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "multiple row changes"? Who is performing these changes? Can you provide more info about this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Google Form to submit values into your spreadsheet, then you could use a [Form submit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) instead, and you can easily get all changes out from it.

Also, depending on your script, you might actually be only listening for one of the [Edit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) events, which also triggers [Change](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change).

Share your script to get more specific help.